# knockout set custom attributes with options binding

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I have a simple select multiple with options binding like below :

```
<select multiple="multiple" width="50" data-bind="options: propositions, optionsText: function(item){ return item.name }, optionsValue: function(item) { return item.name }"></select>
```

this is able to set item.name on the value attribute of the option item like below :

```
<option value=" item.name value here ... "> item.name also here </option>
```

What I would like is to set a custom attribute like this :

```
<option value=" item.name " data-value = " item.name "> item.name also here </option>
```

Is it possible to tell knockout to set the attribute **data-value** in the binding and how would you do that ?

Comment: Yes, you can use `optionsAfterRender`. See a similar answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39648731/how-to-set-data-attribute-value-to-option-when-using-knockout-options-bind

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Intead of using `options` binding you can use `foreach`. In that case you can assign any attributes to the option element:

```
<select multiple="multiple" width="50" data-bind="foreach: propositions">
   <option data-bind="value: name, attr: {'data-value': name}"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch it does exactly what I want !

Comment: @Artem: Hi, I'm new to knockout js and I was looking for a solution as mentioned above. It works perfectly but could you please tell me how can I get the value of the 'data-value' attribute in knockout js?

Comment: Hello, I am not sure that you need data-value attribute, it was required for Arno but usually it is enough to you value binding on select. But it if really need it you can read value assigned to it from "name" observable in your viewmodel which is bounded to it.