# How to set `data` attribute value to `option` when using knockout `options` binding

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

In knockout's [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html), it mentions `optionsAfterRender`. I was trying to add `data` attribute value without succeed.

Here's the sample from the doc:

```
<select size=3 data-bind="
    options: myItems,
    optionsText: 'name',
    optionsValue: 'id',
    optionsAfterRender: setOptionDisable">
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var vm = {
        myItems: [
            { name: 'Item 1', id: 1, disable: ko.observable(false)},
            { name: 'Item 3', id: 3, disable: ko.observable(true)},
            { name: 'Item 4', id: 4, disable: ko.observable(false)}
        ],
        setOptionDisable: function(option, item) {
            ko.applyBindingsToNode(option, {disable: item.disable}, item);
        }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
</script>
```

Here's what I tried but didn't work but also no errors.

```
setOptionDisable: function(option, item) {
    $(option).text(''); // this will blank out the text in options
    $(option).data('test', '123'); // but this won't do anything at all.
    $(option).attr('data-test', '123'); // this worked as pointed out by Matt
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery actually assigns `data attr` but it does not show up on `DOM` element because jQuery saves it in an internal data structure.
If you log your recent data attr you will get the value but you won't see on DOM.

Example :https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/83/

But if you use  `attr()` it does update the dom attribute as well.

Example https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/84/